# criteria for choosing a post-hoc tests

Tags: post-hoc, bonferroni, tukey-hsd-test

After eg. ANOVA there are several post-hoc tests out there (e.g. Tukey, Bonferroni, etc.) but what are the criteria for choosing one over the other?

If one is more conservative, shouldn't we use it always and forget about the others?

Could you suggest a reading with rules of decision on which one to use in different cases?

Answer (score 2):

Tukey, Bonferroni etc. are adjustments for the fact that in pair wise comparison, for each pear you consider, you risk a false positive.

Each of these adjustments starts from a set of assumptions. Some, like Tukey, assume you are going to consider each pear. Others, like Dunnett, you are only going to compare everything with one reference level (control group).